# Python ElementTree adding a child

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an xml file which looks like this:

```
<keyboard>
 
</keyboard>
```

I want to make it look like this:

```
<keyboard>
    
    <keybind key="W-c-a"><action name="Execute"><command>sudo shutdown now</command></action></keybind>

</keyboard>
```

I have a function to add this which has parameters that will change the key and the command. Is this possible to do? If yes, how can I do this?

(The function):

```
def add_keybinding(self, keys, whatToExec):
        
        keybinding = "<keybind key=\"%s\"><action name=\"Execute\"><command>%s</command><action></keybind>" % (keys, whatToExec)
        f = open("/etc/xdg/openbox/rc.xml", "a")
        try:
            # I want to append the keybinding variable to the <keyboard>
        except IOError as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: It should be possible because otherwise it'd be a pretty useless XML manipulation library, don't you agree? Please [do some research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953), then make an attempt and ask a _specific_ question here if you run into problems with your attempt. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], 
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953), 
and provide a [mre]. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#building-xml-documents), you can try the following:

```
def add_keybinding(keys, whatToExec, filename): 
    keybind = ET.Element('keybind')
    keybind.set("key", keys)

    action = ET.SubElement(keybind, 'action')
    action.set("name", "Execute")
    
    command = ET.SubElement(action, 'command')
    command.text = whatToExec

    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    tree.getroot().append(keybind)
    
    tree.write(filename)
```

**Explanation:**

1. Create the `keybind` tag using [`xml.etree.ElementTree.Element`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#element-objects) : `keybind = ET.Element('keybind')`
2. Set a *property* using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.set): `keybind.set("key", keys)`
3. Create the `action` tag as a sub element of `keybind` using
   [`xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.SubElement): `action = ET.SubElement(keybind, 'action')`
4. Set the property as at step 2: `action.set("name", "Execute")`
5. Create *command* tag: `action.set("name", "Execute")`
6. Set `command` tag content using [`.text`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.text): `command.text = whatToExec`
7. Read file using [`xml.etree.ElementTree.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse): `tree = ET.parse(filename)`
8. Append `keybind` tag to the doc root element using [`append`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.append)*
9. Export new *xml* to file using [`write`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write)

---

**Full example**:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

def add_keybinding(keys, whatToExec, filename): 
    keybind = ET.Element('keybind')
    keybind.set("key", keys)

    action = ET.SubElement(keybind, 'action')
    action.set("name", "Execute")
    
    command = ET.SubElement(action, 'command')
    command.text = whatToExec

    tree = ET.parse(filename)
    tree.getroot().append(keybind)
    
    tree.write(filename)
    return tree

def prettify(elem):
    rough_string = ET.tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
    return minidom.parseString(rough_string).toprettyxml(indent="  ")

filename = "test.xml"
for i in range(3):
    tree = add_keybinding(str(i), "whatToExec " + str(i), filename)
    
print(prettify(tree.getroot()))
```

*Output*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<keyboard>
  <keybind key="0">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>whatToExec 0</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="1">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>whatToExec 1</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
  <keybind key="2">
    <action name="Execute">
      <command>whatToExec 2</command>
    </action>
  </keybind>
</keyboard>
```